# ViewFlipper doesn't receive touch events

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am working on an Android project in which I use a `ViewFlipper` for flipping childs. For this I used a customized flipper. In this I override the `onTouchEvent()` method.
The flipper contain images in each child but when I try to flip it doesn't receive any touch event. When I override the `ViewGroup` method `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and return `true`, then flipping is done but due to this my `onClickEvent()` on each image is not received.

I am not getting where the problem is. When I return `false` from `onInterceptTouchEvent()` then the click event is being received but not the touch event.

What am I missing?

Code for the ViewFlipper:

```
public class MyViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {

    static final String logTag = "ViewFlipper";
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 30;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    Animation slideLeftIn;
    Animation slideLeftOut;
    Animation slideRightIn;
    Animation slideRightOut;
    Context context;
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper;

    public MyViewFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        viewFlipper=this;
        this.context=context;
        System.out.println("I am in MyFlipper() counstructor...");
    }

    public MyViewFlipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context=context;
        viewFlipper=this;
        System.out.println("I am in MyFlipper() counstructor...");
        slideLeftIn =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_left_in);
        slideLeftOut =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_left_out);
        slideRightIn =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_right_in);
        slideRightOut =
            AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_right_out);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe horizontal?
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {
                        this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {
                        this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(Math.abs(deltaX)<15){
                        onClickEvent();
                    }
                    //Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX)
                    //+ " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                }
                // swipe vertical?
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {
                        this.onTopToBottomSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {
                        this.onBottomToTopSwipe();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i(logTag, "Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX)
                        + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public void onRightToLeftSwipe() {

        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
        viewFlipper.showNext();
    }

    public void onLeftToRightSwipe() {

        viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
        viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut); 
        viewFlipper.showPrevious();
    }

    public void onTopToBottomSwipe() {
        Log.i(logTag, "onTopToBottomSwipe!");
        // activity.doSomething();
    }

    public void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
        Log.i(logTag, "onBottomToTopSwipe!");
        // activity.doSomething();
    }

    public void onClickEvent(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;    // Here if true then Flipping done.
                        // And if false then click event done. 
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no any error on my logCat. It handled either touch or click event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem.
Here is what i did. I had a listview in my view flipper and i override the `setOnTouchListener()` of my listview and animated the view flipper from there. It worked for me.

Try overriding the `setOnTouchListener()` of `ImageView` in your case.

Comment: Thanks Shafi for reply. But here I just want to clear that my flipper child contain more than one images , means 3 row & 3 column of images(like gird but not used grid). If I implement setOnTouchListener() on image then can I get sufficient & correct movemnt for flipping.

Comment: Hi Shafi, I override setOnTouchListener() on my Image View. Which is work perfect as I want. Thanks for your reply. But I just want to ask There is no any alter native for handling flipper touch & child click event separately.  Thanks You

Comment: I am not sure if there is an alternative.

P.S.- If the answer was useful, please vote up and accept the answer.

Comment: Hi I already Accept your answer and also vote by clicking yes button. If any other process for vote then please inform me I am new on Stack over flow. Thank You